# Starting Jmeter recording proxy from command-line

Tags: automation, jmeter, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, performance-testing

In our CI pipeline we are running automated acceptance tests through selenium. We are now looking to run these through a recording proxy and then use the recording as a basis for a load test.

This strategy will help us automatically add new acceptance tests to the load test. We are currently running load tests with JMeter, hence it would be nice to be able to achieve this using the same tools. However we can't figure out a way to start recording from the JMeter command-line interface. Is this at all possible? If not isn't here other tools that has this feature set?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible as per JMeter 3.1 so you will have to use GUI or go for another tool.

[Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) can be considered as an option, the main features you might be interested in are:

- it's free
- it's open source
- it is command-line application
- it supports [JMeter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) and [Selenium](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) tests (you can use Taurus to execute them in parallel)
- and finally, it comes with [Proxy2JMX Converter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/) module which can be used for **recording Selenium tests in command-line mode** and converting them into a JMeter test plan. Moreover, you will even get automatic correlation of dynamic parameters. See [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) article for details.